# classic asp page httprequest on aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic

I am having trouble finding a way to use httprequest in classic to pull data from an aspx that is also calling a reqeust.

classic code:

```
    HostURL = "https://URL"
    NetURL = "middle.aspx?HostURL=" & HostUR

    Dim oXMLHTTP
    Dim strStatusTest

    Set oXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")

    oXMLHTTP.Open "POST", NetURL, False
    oXMLHTTP.Send
    strStatusText = oXMLHTTP.responseText
```

the netURL aspx code

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
    String host = getParam();
       HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

    String cc;
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
       {
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
          cc = reader.ReadToEnd();
       }       
    Response.Write(cc);
}
```

so what im attempting to do is when i call the aspx page from classic, the aspx on load gets a key that I need the asp page to have.

the aspx code works fine, it does retrieve the key that I need.

additional info: we turned off TLS 1.0 and manager does not want to do the registry fix. I am also a very junior programmer so this might not even work, I don't know.

Thank you in advance for any and all help.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Do you get an error reported?

Comment: There is a syntax error in the classic code line 2, and NetURL being set to `https://URL` is suspect. Also, as you are not sending any data, I suggest you use GET instead of POST. I have often used XMLHTTP in classic ASP and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code

As JohnRC's comment points out - `https://URL` is suspect. I assume though that you've substituted this for an actual URL which you don't want to display on this forum.

NetURL needs to be an absolute URL, ie

```
NetURL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/middle.aspx?HostURL=" & HostURL
```

Also, in the code you've provided you've left the "L" off the end of `HostURL` in the second line, if this is in your actual code then obviously the variable won't be passed to your aspx page.

Finally, it's not an error, but I recommend using `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` rather than 3.0 - it calls the most recent version of MSXML

Answer (score 0):

I am making no comment on why and why not to do this... but I have a good use case.
I wrote a library, and since then 100's of Classic ASP pages (in 1998 to 2005) to use it.
This library handles and wraps the FileSystemObject. But in the newer OS's I have been getting lots of issues with *mappings* . So I decided to start using the ASPX version of this library (used in a lot of ASPX's :-). 
So I turn the ASPX library into a POST webservice by adding a "on this request do this function" code in the lib's main. 
Then I rewrote the FSO.inc to use ServerXMLHTTP to call the FSO.ASPX, with the requests to write/read/delete/whatever the files.
So far, no problems...
In the ASPX, below my public shared global class FSO:

```
<%
Select Case UCase(Current.Request("f"))
Case "READALL":     Response.write( FSO.ReadAll(Current.Request("filename")) )
Case "FILEEXISTS":  Response.write( FSO.FileExists(Current.Request("filename")) )
End select
%>
```

and then in the FSO.inc:

```
function CallFSO(exec)
    Dim objSrvHTTP
    Set objSrvHTTP = Server.CreateObject ("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objSrvHTTP.SetProxy 1
    objSrvHTTP.open "POST", "http://.......your server..../FSO.aspx", False
    objSrvHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    objSrvHTTP.send exec
    IF objSrvHTTP.status = 200 Then CallFSO = objSrvHTTP.responseText
    Set objSrvHTTP = nothing
End function

FUNCTION ReadAll(Filename)
    ReadAll = CallFSO( "f=readAll&FileName=" & filename)
End function

Function FileExists(Filename)
    FileExists = instr(CallFSO( "f=FileExists&FileName=" & filename), "True") > 0
End Function
```

Maybe not the most sufficient solution, but if you have a truck load of ASPs, and no resources to rewrite it, this works...